# C beginner execise , taking integer from user and calculate how many time the number of 1 is in it

Tags: c

my mission was to take integer from a user and calculate how many times the number 1 is in it , here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
int choosen_number;
int count = 0;
int onesnumber = 0;
      scanf("Please enter an integer %d\n",&choosen_number);
      int indicator = choosen_number;
      while (indicator > 0){
        indicator = indicator/10;
        count = count + 1;
      }
      while (count!=0){

        if (choosen_number%10 ==1){
          count = count - 1;
          onesnumber = onesnumber + 1;
        }
        choosen_number = choosen_number /10;

        }


  printf("the number of ones is %d\n",onesnumber );
  }
```

As i am trying to execute it with a number like 12312 it says the number of ones are 0 everytime i try something like that.

Comment: if you're just looking for the `'1'` digit in the number, I wouldn't treat it as a number at all. Input it as a string, iterate through each character and see if it matches `'1'`

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
printf("Please enter an integer ");
scanf(" %d\n",&choosen_number);
```

as the way you have it, choosen_number will read as 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. `scanf` should just contain the format specifier you're scanning for, in addition to a prepended space for ignoring whitespace in `stdin`.

   ```
   printf("Please enter an integer: ");
   scanf(" %d\n", &choosen_number);
   ```
2. In your second `while` loop where you process the number digit-by-digit, you only decrement `count` if the digit you're currently processing is equal to 1. This means that for any number that isn't composed entirely of 1s, you will have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

1 The line

```
scanf("Please enter an integer %d\n",&choosen_number);
```

should be

```
printf("Please enter an integer: ");
scanf("%d", &choosen_number);
```

2 You can do like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int choosen_number;
  int count = 0;

  printf("Please enter an integer: ");
  scanf("%d", &choosen_number);
  while (choosen_number != 0) {
    if (choosen_number%10 == 1)
      ++count;
    choosen_number /= 10;
  }
  printf("the number of ones is %d\n", count);
  return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it without using "if" statement

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int choosen_number,digit,onesnumber =0;      
    printf("Please gine a positive integer\n");
    scanf(" %d",&choosen_number); 
    // Do some error handling here  
    while (choosen_number>0)
    {
        digit=choosen_number%10; 
        onesnumber =onesnumber +(digit==1);//(digit==1) will return 0 or 1
        choosen_number=choosen_number/10;     
    }
    printf("the number of ones is %d\n",onesnumber );
    return 0;
}
```